# How to enrich Camel message using web service?

Tags: java, apache-camel

Does anybody have some sample for this ? In a middle of Camel route I have a message with list of objects. For some of them (based on flag) I want to call a web service and add an additional record to the list with some of the fields set from parent record and some fields received from web service...I tried this:

```
...
.process(new MappingProcessor())
.split(body()).parallelProcessing()
.setHeader("program_id", simple("${body.programId}"))
.wireTap("direct:enrich")
...
```

where I use wireTap to create a message copy which I want aggregate to the result later. Then

```
from("direct:enrich")
.choice()
.when(simple("${in.body.flag} == 1"))
    .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, MyOutput.class)
    .enrich("direct:getValues", new SomeAggregationStrategy());
```

and

```
from("direct:getValues")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple(apiEndpoint + "/getvalue"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple("program_id=${in.header.program_id}"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
    .to("https://dummyhost")
    .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Result.class);
```

I don't event reach my aggregation strategy class where I want to set values based on web service response and I receive a message:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
```

Comment: What kind of body are you dealing with? Does it enter the "when" condition in your choice, in the direct:enrich route?

Comment: I have some kind of data transfer object with 2 dozens for fields. Yes, it enters the 'when' condition, makes correct web service call and returns some data.

Comment: So if it does not get to the aggregation, where does it stop? If it returns the data it must return from the getValues route and enter the aggregation strategy..